# pandas.DataFrame.merge with None (NaN)

Tags: pandas, merge

I need to join the fields containing **None/Nan**. But pandas betrays that, is that normal? (simulate intersect, it's need to keep the indexes of first dframe)

```
a = pandas.DataFrame([[None, 1], [1, 2]], index=[10, 11], columns=['a', 'b'])
b = pandas.DataFrame([[None, 2], [1, 2]], columns=['c', 'd'])

a.merge(
    right=b.drop_duplicates().set_index(b.columns.to_list()),
    how='inner',
    left_on=a.columns.to_list(),
    right_index=True)

#       a  b
# 11  1.0  2
# 11  1.0  2 # Where does this row come from ???
#
# While i was expecting just:
#       a  b
# 11  1.0  2
```

But

```
a = pandas.DataFrame([[None, 1], [1, 2]], index=[10, 11], columns=['a', 'b'])
b = pandas.DataFrame([[None, 1], [1, 2]], columns=['c', 'd'])

a.merge(
    right=b.drop_duplicates().set_index(b.columns.to_list()),
    how='inner',
    left_on=a.columns.to_list(),
    right_index=True)

#       a  b
# 11  1.0  2
# Where is the row [None, 1] ???
#
# While i was expecting:
#       a  b
# 10  NaN  1
# 11  1.0  2
```

How to join with **None** ?

Comment: Please indicate your expected result.

Comment: sorry, added in code)

Comment: Hmm, it seems like `a.merge(b, on='a')` more or less gives what you want.

Comment: No, I need to keep the index a. Also the result is different. But:
    ```a = pd.DataFrame([[None, 1], ['a', 2]], index=[10,11], columns=['a', 'b'])
    b = pd.DataFrame([[None, 1], ['a', 2]], columns=['c', 'd'])

    print(a.merge(b, on=['a', 'b']))
    #       a  b
    # 0  None  1
    # 1     a  2```

Comment: Then you can use `join`: `a.set_index('a').join(b.set_index('a'), rsuffix='_y')` also I find it hard to visualise how you get that merge result from your input. I'm taking a guess here.

Comment: I need to keep the indexes of a, so on the right I am joining the `RightIndex=True`.

Comment: `a.set_index('a').join(b.set_index('a'), rsuffix='_y', how='left')`

Comment: So the original index of `a` is lost

Comment: I updated the post

Comment: This is possibly a merge and filtering problem, does `a[a.merge(b, left_on='a', right_on='c', indicator=True, how='left').eval('_merge == "both"').values]` solve your issue?

Comment: Seems to be related to this open issue: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/25138. Also joins on NaN are considered to be an unwanted behavior, and may change in the future: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/22491